# Build time Type error Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth, npm-scripts, npm-build

```
export default async function Product({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string | undefined };
}) {
  // uri to get single Product from backend
  const filteredData = pagedata.filter((elem) => elem.title == params.slug);
  const pageElems = filteredData[0].content.map((elem) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={elem.title}
        className={`${satoshi.className} inner-elements-company-page`}
        id={elem.title.replaceAll(" ", "_")}
      >
        <h3>{elem.title}</h3>
        <p>{elem.desc}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="total-company-page-component">
        <div className="total-company-heading-container">
          <h1 className={integralCFBold.className}>{params.slug}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="total-company-details-container">{pageElems}</div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = pagedata.map((Elem: { title: { toString: () => any } }) => {
    return {
      params: {
        slug: Elem.title.toString(),
      },
    };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

This is my Code.
I tried to getstatic paths by using data in pagedata.
Please provide a possible fix . The app runs good in localhost without any error.
But the Build command throws the error

Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("D:/Fullstack/e-commerce/frontend-copy/src/app/footer/[slug]/page"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | ... 4 more ... | "generateMetadata", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
Property 'getStaticPaths' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '() => Promise<{ paths: { params: { slug: any; }; }[]; fallback: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

6 |
7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry

> 8 | checkFields<Diff<{
> |             ^
> 9 |   default: Function
> 10 |   config?: {}
> 11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function

This is the Error msg I am getting when I try npm run build command
Please provide me with the posiible fix.